# sql expiry date use Trigger OR Schedule a Job

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I have this table :

[image]

Now, i like the way when the date expires. EndTime < GETDATE()

expire field is true.

What method should I use? use a trigger to true or a schedule job that run before run any  query  in this table?

Comment: I would do neither. Make it a computed column, persisted if need be.

Comment: @SeanGallardy
I do not understand , please explain

Comment: @SeanGallardy I agree (but not on the persisted.) The column can't be persisted as it involves `GETDATE()`. You can post it as an answer (and feel free to use the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae300/1)).

Comment: @ypercube Haha, good call, wasn't paying enough attention. Keeping me honest :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like below should get you started ...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[patientInfo]
(
id int,
patientid int,
  starttime datetime,
  endtime datetime,
  doctorid int
)
GO

ALTER TABLE patientInfo ADD 
    expire AS CASE WHEN endtime < GETDATE()THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
GO

    declare @now datetime=getdate()

INSERT into patientInfo (id, patientid, starttime, endtime, doctorid)
SELECT 1,1,@now,@now-1,1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,2,@now,@now+1,2
UNION ALL SELECT 3,3,@now, @now+2,3
UNION ALL SELECT 4,4,@now, @now-2,4
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d4bbc/13)